# Print formula in google sheets not working in a copy

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula to print in a google sheet:

=LET(sheet_id, "1aLp8dm0SVro7NfxzhTblcUq3T8wtf9ViVkBP4wgQ8DI", HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"&sheet_id&"/export?format=pdf&size=LETTER&fzr=false&fzc=false&portrait=false&scale=2&top_margin=0.75&bottom_margin=0.75&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid=1797144588&range=A1:L59", "PRINT"))

When I force a copy, the new sheet is not printing with changes that are made because they are pointing at the original sheet.

How can this formula be translated so when a copy is made, the formula works for the copy?

I do not know how to make this formula point at the correct sheet.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `When I force a copy, the new sheet is not printing with changes that are made because they are pointing at the original sheet.`. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, the purpose of the sheet is to make a copy each time you fill it out.  When a copy is made, the formula does not work to print (and keep the edits in the sheet).  Ive been told it points at the original sheet, but I want the edits I make to print each time I make a copy of the sheet.